# Is there an English equivalent of the Korean expression: "If the rice cake looks good, then it tastes good"?

Tags: popular-refrains

This Korean saying is essentially the direct opposite of "never judge a book by its cover."

Comment: If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck.

Comment: A shorter form is "If it quacks like a duck, it's a duck".

Comment: @e86 "If the shoe fits, [you can] wear it"  https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_the_shoe_fits#English

Comment: "Follow your instinct and [always] trust appearances". It's not an idiom, but ...

Comment: Are you saying this phrase means "Always judge a book by its cover," usable in both positive and negative situations?  And is there a sense of looking good makes something good?

Comment: I have never heard it used in a derogatory sense.  It is usually used to say something is probably good on the whole when it looks good in appearance.  So "always judge a book by its cover" is probably too strong of an interpretation.

Comment: What's the hangeul for this expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably consider the following in addition to some wonderful suggestions in comments

***What you see is what you get***

> The product you are looking at is exactly what you get if you buy it

[Dictionary.com]

It is a popular phrase in the computer industry. It is abbreviated to WYSIWYG (pronounced as "wiz-ee-wig"). For instance, if you are printing a document, whatever you see on the computer screen will be exactly printed as it is without any changes whatsoever.

For more reading , go [here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/what-you-see-is-what-you-get.html)